# Gateway IP Returns to Zero

Tags: networking

When you set a static IP under Ubuntu 12.04.1, you must supply the desired machine IP and the gateway IP, all using the Network Manager.  When I first entered them and rebooted, everything worked great.  On the second boot, however, Firefox could find no Web page.  Upon checking, I discovered that the gateway IP had returned to zero.  Now, no matter how often I resupply it, it returns to zero immediately after NM "saves" it: that is, appears as zero when redisplayed.  The only way I can get to the Internet is to restore DHCP operation.

I need to use static IP for access to my home network.  Would appreciate any suggestion.

--Robert Smith

Comment: Please use `apport-bug` to file a bug report against the network-manager package.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get network manager to work correctly, you can setup static IP addresses by editing the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.  Full documentation on how to do this can be found in `man interfaces`.  For example, you could setup eth0 to have a static IP address by inserting this into the file:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

After doing this run "sudo restart network-manager" or reboot.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sigh.  I've tried this or similar sequences over and over.  Usually they hang the machine after boot.  Yours merely caused the network not to come up, an improvement.

Comment: Humm... this is quite odd. Perhaps eth0 is not the name of your network adapter? What is the name of the device if you run `ifconfig` in a terminal?  You should have an `ethN` device (with N being an integer) and `lo` for the loopback. Note, if only `lo` shows up, comment out the lines in the files above with a `#` and restart before running `ifconfig`.

Comment: In Ubuntu 12.04 and later you need not and should not edit /etc/resolv.conf directly since the file is dynamically generated. If ifup is used to configure interfaces defined in /etc/network/interfaces then nameserver addresses should also be specified in that file, on a `dns-nameservers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` line in the iface stanza in question.

Comment: The answer (currently) says that NetworkManager should be "disabled" by changing `managed = false` to `managed = true`. Changing `managed = false` to `managed = true` actually causes NetworkManager to emulate `ifup`, obeying /etc/network/interfaces. Please read the manual page NetworkManager.conf(5) and take note of the following warning text: "Remember that NetworkManager controls the default route, so [if an] interface is ignored, NetworkManager may assign the default route to some other interface."